# Increasing Ubuntu (12.04) partition size

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm running a dual-boot Windows XP/Ubuntu system, and I'd like to increase the size of the Ubuntu partition at the expense of the Windows partition.

I've already shrunk the Windows partition, creating a large unallocated space between the Windows and Ubuntu partitions. See screenshot below.

[image]

I'd like to move my Ubuntu partition to the start of the unallocated space, and then increase its size to encompass all of the unallocated space.

Once I try and move it using the GParted liveCD, but it tells me to *expect big GRUB issues* since I'm moving my Ubuntu partition's start sector.

What is it that I should expect, and how do I handle it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's OK, you can easily recover GRUB after the move operation by running [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from a LiveCD/USB (but first you should prepare one if you haven't yet).

Comment: Thanks for the help! GRUB wasn't even fazed by the move, and everything worked smoothly after the partition resize. :)