# Ubuntu 16.04 Increase partition size?

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, hard-drive

I already saw lots of answers here on askubuntu. But **nothing seems to be working**. All the **answers seem confusing a lot**.

I need clear cut idea **if it is possible now to increase the partition size I gave while installation**. If yes then how?

[image]

As per image, **total capacity of that ubuntu partition is only 22.7 GB**, but I will **need more than that** for my applications/softwares.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Edit 1: Anwar, none of the answers helped like >>

Edit 2: Added gparted image.
[image]

[Increasing Ubuntu (12.04) partition size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195193/increasing-ubuntu-12-04-partition-size?rq=1)

[Increase the partition size of Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312576/increase-the-partition-size-of-ubuntu?rq=1)

[Increase Ubuntu 16.04 partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778551/increase-ubuntu-16-04-partition?rq=1)

Comment: Replace the image with the info gparted shows you.

Comment: What answers didn't help? link them in your question

Comment: @Anwar, edited the answer.

Comment: Have you checked the answers of this question? Also follow what Rinzwind said. provide a screenshot from gparted

Comment: @Rinzwind , hi image is added

Comment: @Anwar problem with these q's... disk are often differently partitioned. Resizing is not that difficult but needs to be accurate.

Comment: In your case: from a gparted live session (http://gparted.org/livecd.php so not the OS itself): shrink sda5, creating unallocated space at the end of sda5. Enlarge sda6.

Comment: @Rinzwind, ok fine, I burn Gparted on CD. What next? Could you please be  little clear?

Comment: Oh it is not that difficult. You'll figure it out :D See the link @Pilot6 posted. It has all you need to know.